# Sklearn: KNeighborsRegressor vs KNeighborsClassifer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression, nearest-neighbor

What is the difference between the KNeighborsRegressor and the KNeighborsClassifier of the sklearn library?

I'm trying to use the kNN algorithm to make predictions on a datset that has the names of certain emotions (like happy, sad, angry) as possible classes. The attributes are numerical pixel values. I've learned that these are of the categorical type. I'm using sklearn for the first time and can't decide between the KneighborsRegressor and the KNeighborsClassifier. Is there that much of a difference in my case? In which situations would one use these?

Comment: you should be using the classifier. regression is for predicting continuous values like house prices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`KNeighborsRegressor` and `KNeighborsClassifier` are closely related. Both retrieve some k neighbors of query objects, and make predictions based on these neighbors. Assume the five nearest neighbors of a query x contain the labels [2, 0, 0, 0, 1]. Let's encode the emotions as happy=0, angry=1, sad=2.

The `KNeighborsClassifier` essentially performs a majority vote. The prediction for the query x is 0, which means 'happy'. So this is the way to go here.

The `KNeighborsRegressor` instead computes the mean of the nearest neighbor labels. The prediction would then be `3/5 = 0.6`. But this does not map to any emotion we defined. The reason for that is that the emotions variable is indeed categorical, as stated in the question. 
If you had emotions encoded as a continuous variable, you may use the Regressor. Say the values are in an interval [0.0, 2.0], where 0 means really happy, and 2 means really sad, 0.6 now holds a meaning (happy-ish).

Btw, since you mention logistic-regression in the keywords, don't be confused by the name. It is actually classification, as described in the [scikit-learn user guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression).

Answer (score 0):

I think KNN algorithm style for both is the same. But they have different outputs. One gives you regression and other classification. To understand your question I think you should check how classification and regression differ. Check this link and it will be more clear for you.

[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141381/regression-vs-classification][1]

Answer (score 0):

You can think of KNeighborsRegressor as a method/function used for predicting a value (just as simple linear regression does but using a different way/algorithm).
KNeighborsClassifier has the goal of putting data into different classifications using the KNN algorithm.
One method predicts a value, the other returns the label of a certain group (group a, group b, group c etc).